# How do I add a dynamic list of variable to the command pd.concat

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dynamic, arguments

I am using python3 and pandas to create a script that will:

- Be dynamic across different dataset lengths(rows) and unique values - completed
- Take unique values from column A and create separate dataframes as variables for each unique entry - completed
- Add totals to the bottom of each dataframe - completed
- Concatenate the separate dataframes back together - incomplete

The issue is I am unable to formulate a way to create a list of the variables in use and apply them as arg in to the command pd.concat.

The sample dataset. The dataset may have more unique BrandFlavors or less which is why the script must be flexible and dynamic.

[image]

Script:

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')
excel_file = ('testfile.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
df = df.sort_values(by='This', ascending=False)
colarr = df.columns.values
arr = df[colarr[0]].unique()
for i in range(len(arr)):
    globals()['var%s' % i] = df.loc[df[colarr[0]] == arr[i]]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if globals()['var%s' % i].empty:
        ''
    else: 
        globals()['var%s' % i] = globals()['var%s' % i].append({'BrandFlavor':'Total',
                                'This':globals()['var%s' % i]['This'].sum(),
                                'Last':globals()['var%s' % i]['Last'].sum(),
                                'Diff':globals()['var%s' % i]['Diff'].sum(),
                                '% Chg':globals()['var%s' % i]['Diff'].sum()/globals()['var%s' % i]['Last'].sum() * 100}, ignore_index=True)
        globals()['var%s' % i]['% Chg'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
        globals()['var%s' % i].fillna(' ', inplace=True)
```

I have tried this below, however the list is a series of strings

```
vararr = []
count = 0
for x in range(len(arr)):
    vararr.append('var' + str(count))
    count = count + 1
df = pd.concat([vararr])
```

pd.concat does not recognize a string. I tired to build a class with an arg defined but had the same issue.

The desired outcome would be a code snippet that generated a list of variables that matched the ones created by lines 9/10 and could be referenced by pd.concat([*list, of, vars, here*]). It must be dynamic. Thank you

Comment: please do not use `globals` to make variables, that is not good practice

Comment: Could you try and trim down your question? I'm having a difficult time understanding what you are trying to solve

Comment: MattR: The issue is stated as : The issue is I am unable to formulate a way to create a list of the variables in use and apply them as arg in to the command pd.concat.

Comment: AWS_apprentice: Just a poor image, I will update it. ty

Comment: AWS_apprentice: What is a better way to create vars if not global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixing the issue at hand, you shouldn't use `globals` to make variables, that is not considered *good practice*. Your code should work with some minor modifications.

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings


warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore')

excel_file = ('testfile.xlsx')
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
df = df.sort_values(by='This', ascending=False)


def good_dfs(dataframe):
    if dataframe.empty:
        pass
    else:
        this = dataframe.This.sum()
        last = dataframe.Last.sum()
        diff = dataframe.Diff.sum()
        data = {
            'BrandFlavor': 'Total',
            'This': this,
            'Last': last,
            'Diff': diff,
            'Pct Change': diff / last * 100
        }

        dataframe.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        dataframe['Pct Change'].fillna(0.0, inplace=True)
        dataframe.fillna(' ', inplace=True)

        return dataframe

colarr = df.columns.values
arr = df[colarr[0]].unique()
dfs = []

for i in range(len(arr)):
    temp = df.loc[df[colarr[0]] == arr[i]]
    dfs.append(temp)

final_dfs = [good_dfs(d) for d in dfs]
final_df = pd.concat(final_dfs)
```

Although I will say, there are far easier ways to accomplish what you want without doing all of this, however that can be a separate question.

Comment: Thank you for teh reply: Your code generates the same error as mine did however it is much cleaner code 

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'generator'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: Also 
.
File "<ipython-input-5-fffa5133621b>", line 14
    continue
    ^
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop

.
I had to replace continue with ' ' to proceed

Comment: Amazing, Thank you for the help. I am still learning python and up until now it has mostly been bash script. I am still at the cobbling together others bad practices stage. Thanks to people like you that give your time up to help others learn.